# Django -Join 3 model in query

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class Item(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Gudang Kering', 'Gudang Kering'),
        ('Gudang Basah','Gudang Basah'),
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True,choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, blank= True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Issue(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Granted','Granted'),
        ('Denied','Denied'),
        )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, choices=STATUS)


class Receive(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Granted','Granted'),
        ('Denied','Denied'),
        )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, choices=STATUS)
```

"Hello,sorry im trying to learn django and want to ask,how to write a query to calculate objects where if the 2 have the same item and status granted ,it will calculate stock - quantity(issue) + quantity(receive), i want to save the value to be new value of stock in database"

Answer (score 1):

- Get the object of `Item()` and `Customer()` first as they are set as Foreign Keys in `Issue()`
- Create an object of `Issue()` and assign corresponding values to fields
- To update the `Item.stock` use the `Issue.quantity` and `Item.stock`values which already we have
- Save the instances

```py
# c_id and i_id should be fetched from post or any other way
customer_obj = Customer.objects.get(id=c_id)
item_obj = Item.objects.get(id=i_id)

# create an object of Issue and assign values
issue_obj = Issue()
issue_obj.customer = customer_obj 
issue_obj.item = item_obj
# like so assign values to other fields also and save Issue object
issue_obj.save()

# calculate stock and save the Item object
item_obj.stock = item_obj.stock - issue_obj.quantity
item_obj.save()
```

When Foreign Key is used, the object of the model class should be assigned to that field. eg: `customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)` is a field in `Issue()`. Inorder to save the instance of `Issue()` we need to assign the object of `Customer()` to customer field of Issue object.

Comment: Hello iam sorry AchuthVargese but can you also help me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043875/django-if-condition-in-view-py

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store same information twice. It will make this solution more confusing. You can add these values in runtime. For example:

Solution One: You can just [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) the value of quantity in the queryset directly. No need to store that additional information in the stock attribute of `Item` model. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F, Sum

items = Item.objects.annotate(issue_q=Sum('issue__quantity', filter=Q(issue__status="GRANTED")).annotate(total=F('stock')-F('issue_q'))

for item in items:
   print(item.total)
```

Solution Two: add a property method to display total value:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   ...

   @property
   def total(self):
      return self.stock - self.item_set.filter(status="GRANTED").aggregate(quantity_s=Sum('quantity'))['quantity_s']


for item in Item.objects.all():
   print(item.total)
```

BTW, this solutions is less efficient then first, as it makes multiple queries to DB.

Comment: I see so for example if i want it to make changes efficiently, i put the query of the first in the form save method,this way the quantity only changed when i saved like that?(sorry english is not my first langguage)

Comment: You do not need to save anything to be honest. If you are displaying the total stock information somewhere in view, you can use the annotated data shared here. Or you can run validations based on total value. I don't recommend saving data twice, as it will arise more complcation later. If you are unclear about how to use annotation, then consider second method or read the django docs. Thanks

Comment: sorry ruddra can u explain the quantity_s?,i get the self.stock is from item table but i don't know the quantity_s