# Django Form If condition in view.py with 2 instance

Tags: django, if-statement, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

TO SAVE DATA that is inputted in form in Django i tried tomake it like this
I put this in my model.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Gudang Kering', 'Gudang Kering'),
        ('Gudang Basah','Gudang Basah'),
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True,choices=CATEGORY)
    reorderlevel = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    maxreorderlevel = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, blank= True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Granted','Granted'),
        ('Denied','Denied'),
        )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, choices=STATUS)
```

Then in view.py i define the form like this

```
def updateIssue(request, pk):
    issue = Issue.objects.get(id=pk)
    item = Item.objects.all()
    form = UpdateIssueForm(instance=issue)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateIssueForm(request.POST,instance=issue)
        #print ('printing:',request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            if instance.status == 'Granted':
                item.stock -= instance.quantity
                instance.save()
                item.save()
            else:
        instance.save()

        return redirect('/')
    

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/issue_form.html',context)``
```

The Goal
if instance == "Granted"
the item.stock will be decreased on the amount of instance.quantity
and will be saved.
else
instance will just be saved without affecting the stock from the  2nd model

The error

```
    item = Item.objects.all()
```

even when called the item.stock have 0 attribute even when i have input data in database for that table

Comment: is the `issue_items()` shown here same as in your views code.. there are some typos

Comment: fixed typo onjects to objects

Comment: after if statement indendation is not proper

Comment: the new error is now that the item.stock that i called have no attribute, even when i have caled it first with the ``item = item.objects.all()```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get `Item` since we can access the `Item` related to `Issue` using the `Issue` object like `issue.item`. This is just an example from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

Article model has a field reporter which is a ForeignKey realted to Reporter model. Using Article object the Reporter object is accessed.

```
>>> new_article = r.article_set.create(headline="John's second story", pub_date=date(2005, 7, 29))
>>> new_article
<Article: John's second story>
>>> new_article.reporter
<Reporter: John Smith>
>>> new_article.reporter.id
1
```

Like so, we can access the `Item` using `Issue`

```py
def updateIssue(request, pk):
    issue = Issue.objects.get(id=pk)  # we have our Issue here
    form = UpdateIssueForm(instance=issue)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateIssueForm(request.POST,instance=issue)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            if instance.status == 'Granted':
                issue.item.stock -= instance.quantity   # access Item by using Issue object's related field with name item
                issue.item.save() # save the Item first
                instance.save() # then the Issue
            else: 
                instance.save()

        return redirect('/')
    

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/issue_form.html',context)
```